# Apache Spark on HDFS: read 10k-100k of small files at once

Tags: java, apache-spark, hdfs

I could have up to 100 thousands of small files (each 10-50 KB). They all are stored at HDFS with block size 128 MB. I have to read them at once with Apache Spark, as below:

```
// return a list of paths to small files
List<Sting> paths = getAllPaths(); 
// read up to 100000 small files at once into memory
sparkSession
    .read()
    .parquet(paths)
    .as(Encoders.kryo(SmallFileWrapper.class))
    .coalesce(numPartitions);
```

### Problem

[The number of small files is not a problem from the perspective of memory consumption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43849821/hdfs-behavior-on-lots-of-small-files-and-128-mb-block-size). The problem is the speed of reading of that amount of files. It takes 38 seconds to read 490  small files, and 266 seconds to read 3420 files. I suppose it would take a lot to read 100.000 files.

### Questions

*Will HAR or sequence files speed up Apache Spark batch read of 10k-100k of small files? Why?*

*Will HAR or sequence files slow down persisting of that small files? Why?*

### P.S.

Batch read is the only operation required for that small files, I don't need to read them by id or anything else.

Comment: Hadoop has a standard workaround, commonly used in Hive to read small "streamed" files (cf. my comment in your previous question) and you are not the first Spark-ikaze to stumble on that problem -- cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623402/apache-spark-on-yarn-large-number-of-input-data-files-combine-multiple-input-f

Answer (score 4):

From that post: [How does the number of partitions affect `wholeTextFiles` and `textFiles`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906583/how-does-the-number-of-partitions-affect-wholetextfiles-and-textfiles)

> `wholeTextFiles` uses `WholeTextFileInputFormat` ... Because it extends `CombineFileInputFormat`, it will try to combine
>   groups of smaller files into one partition ... Each record in the RDD
>   ... has the entire contents of the file

Confirmation in the Spark 1.6.3 Java API documentation for `SparkContext`
http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/index.html

> `RDD<scala.Tuple2<String,String>> wholeTextFiles(String path, int
>   minPartitions)`
>  Read a directory of text files from HDFS, a local
>   file system (available on all nodes), or any Hadoop-supported file
>   system URI.

Confirmation in the source code (branch 1.6) comments for class `WholeTextFileInputFormat`
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/input/WholeTextFileInputFormat.scala

> A `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileInputFormat` for
>   reading whole text files. Each file is read as key-value pair, where the key is the file path and
>   the value is the entire content of file.

---

For the record, **Hadoop `CombineInputFormat`** is the standard way to stuff multiple small files in a single Mapper; it can be used in Hive with properties `hive.hadoop.supports.splittable.combineinputformat` and `hive.input.format`.

**Spark `wholeTextFiles()`** reuses that Hadoop feature, with two drawbacks:

*(a)* you have to consume a whole directory, can't filter out files by name before loading them (you can only filter *after* loading)
*(b)* you have to post-process the RDD by splitting each file into multiple records, if required

That seems to be a viable solution nonetheless, cf. that post: [Spark partitioning/cluster enforcing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39818756/spark-partitioning-cluster-enforcing)

---

Or, you can build your own **custom** file reader based on that same Hadoop `CombineInputFormat`, cf. that post: [Apache Spark on YARN: Large number of input data files (combine multiple input files in spark)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623402/apache-spark-on-yarn-large-number-of-input-data-files-combine-multiple-input-f)

Comment: thank you for the answer! I've already implemented that stuff through sequence files `saveAsHadoopFile(path, String.class, SmallFileWrapper.class, SequenceFileOutputFormat.class)`. Could you pls compare sequence files with `wholeTextFiles` solutions? Which is better and when?

Comment: Duh... IMHO `wholeTextFiles` is a stop-gap solution, when you have a swarm of small test files that you need to read efficiently in one pass (then reprocess in memory). Now, if you want to consolidate the data first (e.g. Write-Once-Read-Many times scenario) all the options are open -- file format, compression, etc. It depends.